# Change string color in rich text box if it contains X

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, richtextbox

I have a Jar file that gives output and a rich text box to which the output is written to. Each string that the Jar file gives is a new line in the rich text box. I want, if the line contains certain keywords, to change it's color. I tried the following:

```
if (textR.Contains("[INFO]"))
{
    //txtboxServerOutput.Text += textR + "\n";
    txtboxServerOutput.SelectedText = textR;
    txtboxServerOutput.SelectionColor = Color.Aqua;
}
else
{
    txtboxServerOutput.Text += textR + "\n";
}
```

That results in a messed up output. The rich text box has colored some of the text that contains "[INFO]", but not all, and everything is one line. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you set `txtboxServerOutput.Multiline=true` ?

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan Yes, when I only use `txtboxServerOutput.Text += textR + "\n";` the output is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended it up creating an overload for `AppendText`:

```
// Adds new overload for AppendText for rich textboxes
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
        public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox txtbox, string text, Color color)
        {
            txtbox.SelectionStart = txtbox.TextLength;
            txtbox.SelectionLength = 0;

            txtbox.SelectionColor = color;
            txtbox.AppendText(text);
            txtbox.SelectionColor = txtbox.ForeColor;
        }
};
```

So now I can do this:

```
richTextBox.AppendText("some random text", Color.Blue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
if (textR.Contains("[INFO]"))
{
    txtboxServerOutput.SelectionColor = Color.Aqua;
}
txtboxServerOutput.SelectedText = textR + "\n";
```